# Log4j Properties file upgrade for log4j 2.X

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

We are upgrading Log4J from 1.X to 2.X. This is the old log4J properties file-

I have figured out how to write to a rolling file appender and console from the documentation and some research. But as I am new to the logging framework, having a hard time how to map the loggers for the third-party libraries/ frameworks ( like spring framework in the old properties file)

Would appreciate it if someone can provide any pointers.

Old log4j.properties-

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, fileout


log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=INFO, stdout, fileout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy=INFO, stdout, fileout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.metadata=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.target=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.intercept=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.intercept.method=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.intercept.web=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.afterinvocation=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.acl=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.acl.basic=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.taglibs.authz=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme=INFO , fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.ui=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.ui.rmi=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.ui.httpinvoker=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.util=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.providers.dao=INFO, fileout
#log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity=DEBUG, stdout, fileout
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener=OFF
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsImpl.queryExecuted=OFF
log4j.org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement = ERROR, fileout, console

log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager=INFO, fileout

log4j.logger.org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread=INFO, fileout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker=ERROR, fileout


# Console output...


log4j.defaultInitOverride = false
log4j.rootCategory = INFO, console


log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %-5p [%c.%M()] (%t) %m%n

# Rolling log file output...
log4j.appender.fileout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileout.File=logs/restAPIlog.log
#log4j.appender.fileout.File=${webapp.root}/WEB-INF/log4j.log
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxFileSize=2048KB
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxBackupIndex=9
log4j.appender.fileout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.conversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %-5p [%c.%M()] (%t) %m%n


# Report logging
reportlogging.directory=logs
```

New log4j2.properties-

```
status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig
 
property.filename = logs/restAPIlog.log

 
appenders = console, rolling
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %-5p [%c.%M()] (%t) %m%n


 
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${filename}-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %-5p [%c.%M()] (%t) %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
 

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = console, rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

pom.xml-

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: What is your target format? The Logj 1.x bridge can automatically convert a `log4j.properties` to a `log4j2.xml` file or even use the original `log4j.properties` file.

Comment: Sorry for missing out on the new log4j2.properties and my maven dependency. I have added it to my post. We have to programmatically create new log files and I as per the documentation bridge doesn't support adding appenders programmatically.

Comment: And we also change the logging level through the code. And bridge wont allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Remark first that there is a potential problem in your Log4j 1.x configuration: every logger by default logs also to its parent's appenders. This is called *"additivity"* in Log4j. E.g. messages sent to `org.acegisecurity.intercept.method` will be logged 4 times to the `fileout` logger. The way to correct it in Log4j 1.x is to set additivity to `false`:

```
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity.intercept.method=INFO, fileout
log4j.additivity.org.acegisecurity.intercept.method=false
```

You can easily convert the excerpt above into a Log4j 2.x `<Logger>` tag (XML syntax):

```xml
<Logger name="org.acegisecurity.intercept.method" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="fileout" />
</Logger>
```

The properties syntax is much more verbose, but can be easily deduced from the XML syntax:

```
logger.<identifier1>.name=org.acegisecurity.intercept.method
logger.<identifier1>.level=INFO
logger.<identifier1>.additivity=false
logger.<identifier1>.appenderRef.<identifier2>.ref=fileout
```

where `<identifier1>` and `<identifier2>` are strings without dots.

Comment: Replace `fileout` with `RollingFile`, since you renamed your rolling file appender in `log4j2.properties`.

Comment: Yes, I have been using RollingFile. Here is a sample- `logger.logger1.name=org.springframework.security logger.logger1.level=INFO logger.logger1.additivity=false logger.logger1.appenderRef.id1.ref=RollingFile`.
 Should <identifier2> be one of the appenders?

Comment: It's correct as it is. I am not sure how verbose is `org.springframework.security`, maybe increase the level to `DEBUG` for testing.

Comment: Tried changing the level to `DEBUG`, still the same results. Also tried setting the `-Dlog4j2.debug` to true and don't see anything helpful in log files.